# How to unset vim mode in shell

Tags: shell, vim

I've set the keymaps of shell using `set -o vi` but how do I exit vim mode in shell? Executing `:q` or anything doesn't seem to work. `unset -o vi` returns `bad option -o`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot unset a keymap, you can only change it:

```
set -o emacs
```

Because `emacs` is the default keymap.